# How can I change session storage path in Lumen 5.2.x

Tags: php, configuration, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

I am using Lumen for API development and uses Windows box to develop them, while trying to deploy it for testing on a CentOS 7 box I am getting following error:

```
> Lumen (5.2.5) (Laravel Components 5.2.*) Fatal error: Uncaught
> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Unknown:
> open(/tmp/sess_256709456767027352b0afedbc9bd91b, O_RDWR) failed:
> Permission denied (13)' in Unknown:0 Stack trace: #0 [internal
> function]:
> Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(2,
> 'Unknown: open(/...', 'Unknown', 0, Array) #1 {main} thrown in Unknown
> on line 0
```

Lumen by default do not come with config/session.php, so I tried giving custom path by creating a file but no luck so far.

Comment: How are you serving your app?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for your Apache user on the `tmp` folder?

Comment: Good question, Apache don't have permissions on the tmp folder but this was a whm/cpanel - though I had access to root user I did not want to take any risk so I did below as I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I will have to load the session config by making an entry into the bootstrap/app.php by adding following line:

```
$app->configure('session');
```

This would read path I setup in config/session.php, which I changed to /storage/framework/session

I hope this is reliable enough.